# If $f:X\to Y$ is a one-to-one continuous mapping, and $Y$ is a $T_{2}$-space, then does $X$ too have to be a $T_{2}$-space?

Tags: general-topology

Motivation:

For any two points $y_{1},y_{2}\in Y$, there are disjoint open sets containing $y_{1}$ and $y_{2}$ separately, as $Y$ is a $T_{2}$-space. 
Say $f(x_{1})=y_{1}$ and $f(x_{2})=y_{2}$. Then, taking the inverses of the disjoint open sets, we get disjoint open sets containing $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ separately.

Why the inverses of disjoint open sets are also disjoint is if there was one point in common between two open sets in $X$ and not in $Y$, then that point would mapped to two different points in $Y$, one in each disjoint set, which is impossible.

Remember $f$ is one-to-one. Hence, as there are disjoint open sets for every $y_{i}$ and $y_{j}$, there are correponding open sets for every $x_{i}$ and $x_{j}$. Doesn't this make $X$ a Hausdorff space too?

Comment: You gave all the details of the proof that $X$ is Hausdorff, why are you asking the question?

Comment: Yes it's right.

Comment: That looks good to me.

Comment: Oh. Actually I asked this question because my textbook says "_If $f$ is a one-to-one continuous mapping of $X$ to a $T_{2}$ space, then $f$ is also open._"I arrived upon my conclusion independently. Just wanted to confirm whether this was indeed right.

Comment: There was an additional question I intended to ask. If $X$ too is Hausdorff, and the function is one-to-one, then the function is open anyway! Irrespective of whether $X$ is compact or not. My textbook says **this condition is true if $X$ is compact.** Is this then an unnecessary condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right about the situation when $f: X \to Y$ is continuous, 1-1 and onto, and $Y$ is Hausdorff then so is $X$. The proof you sketched is correct: the images of distinct points are distinct and they have disjoint neighbourhoods that we can pull back.

In the comments you asked about openness. It is *not* true that $f$ needs to be an open map. A standard example: $X = [0,2\pi)$, $Y= S^1 \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, the unit circle, and $f(x) = (\cos(x),\sin(x))$. This map is not open. E.g. consider $f[[0,\pi)]$ and note that $[0,\pi)$ is open in $[0,2\pi)$.

But if $X$ is compact as well, then the map $f$ will be closed and so $f$ is a homeomorphism (and thus open as well).

Answer (score 1):

You  are right. However we can conclude that

> **If $f:X\to Y$ is a one-to-one continuous mapping, and $Y$ is a $T_{3}$-space, then $X$ don't have to be $T_3$.**

**Example 1:** Consider the space $X$ with [Minimal Hausdorff Topology.](http://austinmohr.com/home/?page_id=248&spaceID=100) It is $T_2$, non $T_3$. However it is submetrizable, i.e., there exists a one-to-one continuous mapping from $X$ to a metrizable space. Note that every metrizable space is $T_3$.

**$X$ is submetrizable.**

> **Prove:** $X$ is countable, then $X$ is separable and has a zeroset diagonal. Every separable space with a zeroset diagonal is submetrizable.